# Несколько CKeditor 5 на одной странице

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Как сделать несколько CKEditor5 на одной странице?
такой код не работает

```
ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelectorAll( '.editor' ), {
            minHeight: '300px'
            ,
            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json'
            },
            toolbar: ['ckfinder', '|', 'heading', '|','bulletedList','|','numberedList','|',
                'blockQuote','|', 'bold','|', 'italic', '|', 'undo', 'redo','insertTable','link'
            ],
            heading: {
                options: [
                    { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Параграф', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                    { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Заголовок 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                    { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Заголовок 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                    { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Заголовок 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
                    { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Заголовок 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                    { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Заголовок 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
                    { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Заголовок 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' },
                ]
            }
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log( error );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.editor');
    for (let i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {

        ClassicEditor
            .create( allEditors[i], {
                minHeight: '300px'
                ,
                ckfinder: {
                    uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json'
                },
                toolbar: ['ckfinder', '|', 'heading', '|','bulletedList','|','numberedList','|',
                    'blockQuote','|', 'bold','|', 'italic', '|', 'undo', 'redo','insertTable','link','|'
                ],
                heading: {
                    options: [
                        { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Параграф', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                        { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Заголовок 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                        { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Заголовок 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                        { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Заголовок 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
                        { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Заголовок 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                        { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Заголовок 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
                        { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Заголовок 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' },
                    ]
                }
            })
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
            });
    }
```